# Redux is not getting any data

Tags: redux

I'm new to Redux. It's really confusing to understand basic syntax. None of the bugs are found so It's hard to figure out what's wrong with my code.

It worked well last week, I don't remember what I have changed.

*//child component*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { SingleDatePicker } from 'react-dates';
import moment from 'moment';

class InputForms extends Component {
  state = {
    inputs: ['input-0'],
    title: '',
    tag: '',
    createdAt: moment(),
    imageLinks: [''],
    calendarFocused: false,
    error: '',
  }
  appendInput(e) {
    const newInput = `input-${this.state.inputs.length}`;
    this.setState({ inputs: this.state.inputs.concat([newInput]) });
  }
  onTitleChange = (e) => {
    const title = e.target.value;
    this.setState(() => ({ title }));
  };
  onTagChange = (e) => {
    const tag = e.target.value;
    this.setState(() => ({ tag }));
  };
  onImageLinkChange = (e) => {
    const imageLinks = e.target.value;
    this.setState(() => ({ imageLinks: this.state.imageLinks.concat([imageLinks]) }));
  };
  onDateChange = (createdAt) => {
    if (createdAt) {
      this.setState(() => ({ createdAt }));
    }
  };
  onFocusChange = ({ focused }) => {
    this.setState(() => ({ calendarFocused: focused }));
  };
  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!this.state.title || !this.state.imageLinks) {
      this.setState(() => ({ error: '제목과 이미지링크를 입력해주세요' }));
    } else {
      this.setState(() => ({ error: '' }));
      this.props.onSubmit({
        title: this.state.title,
        tag: this.state.tag,
        createdAt: this.state.createdAt.valueOf(),
        imageLinks: this.state.imageLinks,
      });
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="제목을 입력하세요"
            required
            value={this.state.title}
            onChange={this.onTitleChange}
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="태그를 입력하세요"
            value={this.state.tag}
            onChange={this.onTagChange}
          />
          <SingleDatePicker
            date={this.state.createdAt}
            onDateChange={this.onDateChange}
            focused={this.state.calendarFocused}
            onFocusChange={this.onFocusChange}
            numberOfMonths={1}
            isOutsideRange={() => false}
          />
          {this.state.inputs.map((input, key) => {
            return <input
              key={input}
              type="text"
              required
              value={this.state.imageLinks}
              onChange={this.onImageLinkChange}
              placeholder={`이미지링크 ${key + 1}`}
            />
          })}
          <button>저장</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default InputForms;
```

//parent component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from '../store/configureStore';
import InputForms from './InputForms';
import { addPost } from '../actions/posts';

const store = configureStore();

class CreatePost extends Component {
  onSubmit = (post) => {
    this.props.addPost(post);
    this.props.history.push('/');
  };
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <InputForms onSubmit={this.onSubmit}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, props) => ({
  addPost: (post) => dispatch(addPost(post))
});

export default connect(undefined, mapDispatchToProps)(CreatePost);
```

//index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import AppRouter from './routers/AppRouter';
import 'normalize.css/normalize.css';
import './style/style.css';
import 'react-dates/lib/css/_datepicker.css';
import 'react-dates/initialize';

const store = configureStore();
const jsx = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <AppRouter />
    </Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render(jsx, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

//action
    import database from '../firebase/firebase';

```
//Add Posts
export const addPost = (post) => ({
    type: 'ADD_POST',
    post
});
```

//reducer

```
const postReducerDefaultState = [];

export default (state = postReducerDefaultState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_POST':
            return [
                ...state,
                action.post
            ];
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your reducer, you return as below

```
return [ ...state, action.post];
```

Reducer doesnt return array, but instead returning objects. Secondly, `action.post` is a value, you need to assign this to key, something like below:

```
return { ...state, post: action.post };
```